# Troubles on running an existing project in IONIC2 Windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, npm, ionic2

I am having troubles on running an existing project in IONIC2;

================================================================================
Here you see the message on running 'ionic info' in the project folder:

```
[0x7FFC5C1370E3] ANOMALY: use of REX.w is meaningless (default operand size is 64)
******************************************************
Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:
Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`
******************************************************
Your system information:
[0x7FFC5C1370E3] ANOMALY: use of REX.w is meaningless (default operand size is 64)
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3-201612122136
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.17
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.9.2
Xcode version: Not installed
```

================================================================================
Here you see the version of the packages installed in my computer:

```
cordova -v: 6.3.1
ionic -v: 2.1.17
node -v: v6.9.2
npm -v: 3.10.9
```

================================================================================
Here you see the error on running 'npm install' in my project folder:

```
[0x7FFC5C1370E3] ANOMALY: use of REX.w is meaningless (default operand size is 64)
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.4.0 should be installed with -g

> node-sass@3.10.1 install C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

[0x7FFC5C1370E3] ANOMALY: use of REX.w is meaningless (default operand size is 64)
Start downloading binary at https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.10.1/win32-x64-48_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.10.1/win32-x64-48_binding.node":

tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=403

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@3.10.1 postinstall C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

[0x7FFC5C1370E3] ANOMALY: use of REX.w is meaningless (default operand size is 64)
Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuil
d --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
[0x7FFC5C1370E3] ANOMALY: use of REX.w is meaningless (default operand size is 64)
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\work\\projetos\\uc-mobile-benef\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.4.0
gyp info using node@6.9.2 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "C:\Python27\python.exe" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp verb check python version `C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned:
 "2.7.3\r\n"
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 6.9.2
gyp verb command install [ '6.9.2' ]
gyp verb install input version string "6.9.2"
gyp verb install installing version: 6.9.2
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 6.9.2
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass\build
gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass\build
gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass\build\config
.gypi
gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypi
gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp info spawn args [ 'C:\\work\\projetos\\uc-mobile-benef\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-G',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=auto',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\work\\projetos\\uc-mobile-benef\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\work\\projetos\\uc-mobile-benef\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\t0309\\.node-gyp\\6.9.2\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\t0309\\.node-gyp\\6.9.2',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\work\\projetos\\uc-mobile-benef\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\work\\projetos\\uc-mobile-benef\\node_modules\\node-sass',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\work\\projetos\\uc-mobile-benef\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp verb command build []
gyp verb build type Release
gyp verb architecture x64
gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\t0309\.node-gyp\6.9.2
gyp verb found first Solution file build/binding.sln
gyp verb could not find "msbuild.exe" in PATH - finding location in registry
gyp verb "Release" dir needed to be created? null
gyp verb copying "node.lib" for x64 C:\Users\t0309\.node-gyp\6.9.2\Release\node.lib
gyp info spawn C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]
Compilando os projetos desta solução um de cada vez. Para habilitar a compilação paralela, adicione a opção "/m".
Compilação de 13/12/2016 13:54:57 iniciada.
Projeto "C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" no nó 1 (destinos padrão).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Compilando a configuração de solução "Release|x64".
O destino "Midl" listado em um atributo BeforeTargets em "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustom
izations\masm.targets (28,5)" não existe no projeto e será ignorado.
O destino "CustomBuild" listado em um atributo AfterTargets em "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Build
Customizations\masm.targets (29,5)" não existe no projeto e será ignorado.
O projeto "C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (1) está compilando "C:\work\proj
etos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (2) no nó 1 (destinos padrão).
O projeto "C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (2) está compilando
"C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" (3) no nó 1 (destinos padrão).
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform.Targets(23,7): error MSB8007: The Platf
orm for project 'libsass.vcxproj' is invalid.  Platform='x64'. You may be seeing this message because you are trying to
 build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Platform that doesn't exist for this project
. [C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj]
Projeto de compilação pronto "C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" (desti
nos padrão) -- FALHA.

Projeto de compilação pronto "C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (
destinos padrão) -- FALHA.

Projeto de compilação pronto "C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (destinos padr
ão) -- FALHA.


FALHA da compilação.

"C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (destino padrão) (1) ->
"C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (destino padrão) (2) ->
"C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" (destino padrão) (3) ->
(InvalidPlatformError destino) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform.Targets(23,7): error MSB8007: The Pla
tform for project 'libsass.vcxproj' is invalid.  Platform='x64'. You may be seeing this message because you are trying
to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Platform that doesn't exist for this proje
ct. [C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj]

    0 Aviso(s)
    1 Erro(s)

Tempo Decorrido 00:00:00.93
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\work\\projetos\\uc-mobile-benef\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin
\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"an
y"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3-201612122136 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.2.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3-201612122136 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.2.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3-201612122136 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@2.2.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3-201612122136 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.2.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3-201612122136 requires a peer of @angular/forms@2.2.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3-201612122136 requires a peer of @angular/http@2.2.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3-201612122136 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.2.1 but none was installed
.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3-201612122136 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.2.1 but none was i
nstalled.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3-201612122136 requires a peer of @angular/platform-server@2.2.1 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "ins
tall"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-sass@3.10.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.10.1 postinstall script 'node scripts/build.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-sass
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\work\projetos\uc-mobile-benef\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: most likely a problem with the node-sass package

Comment: Look mostly like cannot download nodesass because of gfw